# Syntax error. Unexpected token when importing THREE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following, and the code runs when I don't import this line:

```
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber/native';
```

This is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber/native';
 
type Props = {};
export default class MyApp extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.js
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2A2734',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: 'white'
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#B0B0B0',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

// You must register the main component
// with the same name as the project
AppRegistry.registerComponent(
  'my-rn-app', () => MyApp
);
```

And this is the error message:

```
SyntaxError: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9F5DA5AC-EFAF-4212-9C6D-2A8C02F52F9F/Documents/apps/MY-RN-APPA6763671-7979-46F5-997F-564C93F38391/src/node_modules/three/examples/js/exporters/GLTFExporter.js: Unexpected token (689:34)
  687 | 
  688 |             console.warn( 'THREE.GLTFExporter: Merged metalnessMap and roughnessMap textures.' );
> 689 |             const metalness = metalnessMap?.image;
      |                                            ^
  690 |             const roughness = roughnessMap?.image;
  691 |             const width = Math.max( metalness?.width || 0, roughness?.width || 0 );
  692 |             const height = Math.max( metalness?.height || 0, roughness?.height || 0 );
    at t.ie.raise (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:468453)
    at t.$.unexpected (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:421786)
    at t.re.parseExprAtom (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:457116)
    at t.parseExprAtom (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:513873)
    at t.re.parseExprSubscripts (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:452009)
    at t.re.parseMaybeUnary (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:451592)
    at t.re.parseExprOps (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:450162)
    at t.re.parseMaybeConditional (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:449753)
    at t.re.parseMaybeAssign (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:448980)
    at t.parseMaybeAssign (/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9583CB65-FEAC-4E72-A943-3188211F7B28/CodeSandbox.app/transpiler.js:1:513077)Compilation failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. (playdotjs.Compiler.Error error 0.)
```

Comment: Looks like whatever you're using as a transpiler does not support optional chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: I set the react native runtime and ran on https://apps.apple.com/us/app/codesandbox/id1423330822